# Forked Function not assigning pointer

Tags: c, pointers, fork

In the code below I have a function `int GetTempString(char Query[]);`
calling it in main works fine.

However, when calling the function from a fork the fork hangs (stops running, no errors, no output) before this line: `pch = strtok (Query," ,");` the **printf shows that the pointer to pch is null**. Again this only happens when the fork is executing it.

What am I doing doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
if((Timer =fork())==-1) printf("Timer Fork Failed");    
    else if(Timer==0)
    {
        while(1)
        {       
        sleep(2);       
        GetTempString("ch 1,2,3,4");        
        }
    }
    else
    {
         //CODE

         GetTempString("ch 1,2,3,4");
        }
}

int GetTempString(char Query[])
{
        char * pch;


    printf("DEBUG: '%s'-'%d'\n",Query,pch);

    pch = strtok (Query," ,");//* PROBLEM HERE*

        //while loop for strtok...

        return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` modifies the string pointed to by its first argument (replacing delimiter characters with NULs), but you're passing in a string literal, which is implicitly const.  You need to copy the string into a writable buffer before calling strtok.

With your example, this happens in both processes, so both will crash.  When posting an abbreviated example to demonstrate a problem, be sure to compile and test it first to make sure it actually shows the problem you're having and not some completely unrelated problem (which may be the case here).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning  a local variable, so you have undefined behaviour - anything could happen after that. You need to allocate the string you are returning dynamically using malloc(), or pass it to the function as a parameter.

Comment: I removed the local variable and it has the same behaviour.

the function call on the main wasn't actually being called like demonstrated, I wished only to convey that it did work. Therefore the first time it is called is by the fork.

Answer (score 0):

TempString variable is allocated on GetTempString function's stack. Using this variable makes sens only inside the context of GetTempString. Use static TempString[50] in order to solve this problem.

Comment: the local was removed, the behaviour is still the same